# How to send my content to a global IPFS node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

To use IPFS in NodeJS, I require `ipfs` module. To connect a IPFS node I try:

```
const IPFS=require("ipfs");
const node= await IPFS.create();
```

After that, When I run NodeJS in PowerShell, The below messages emerge:

```
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.100/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.88.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.49.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
```

I think the above messages are mentioning that I connected to a local IPFS node. If my thought is true, It can be because of `IPFS.create()`. So, I should put a gateway as an argument to that to connecting a global node. I saw some IPFS public gateways on [Public Gateway Checker](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) but I don't know how to put one sample in `IPFS.create()`;

Please giude me:

1. Am I right about the messages on PowerShell?
2. How to use a global IPFS gateway in my code?

My whole NodeJS code:

```
const IPFS=require("ipfs");
    async function register(){
        const node=await IPFS.create();
        node.add("Main Content!").then(function(ipfsHash){console.log(ipfsHash)});
    }
```

Whole result in PowerShell:

```
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.100/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.88.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.49.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/p2p/12D3KooWCGvmbySrpdCVKACJPjZeeUiMR6gSQffa7W3gWZLSGBxp
{
  path: 'QmUaTPt2Uus46Cgo4YMKze8PpHrCKvZ1YXD2zpffNt8U9S',
  cid: CID(QmUaTPt2Uus46Cgo4YMKze8PpHrCKvZ1YXD2zpffNt8U9S),
  size: 21,
  mode: 420,
  mtime: undefined
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `create()`, the client connects to a local node the URL `http://localhost:5001`. To connect to another HTTP gateway to a global node, simply pass the gateway's URL instead.

```
const client = await IPFS.create("https://<your-preferred-gateway>");
const { cid } = await client.add("Your content");
```

See also: [`create` options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client#createoptions)